# Merging many GeoTIFF files give huge space while processing

Tags: qgis, raster, r

While I was merging eight GeoTIFF files with each of files has 800MB-1GB of size, on the log of Merge tools in QGIS give me those error, which requires more than 3000GBs of free space. How it can be that? How to merge it effectively?

I already try in RStudio but the process is too long and eat my disk C for the temporary files.

[image: QGIS]

EDITED(1)
My current imageries are like this, with each tile has size of 0.25x0.25 degrees. Are the blank area still counted as new raster and calculated in the size too?
[image: My imageries]

EDITED(2)
I already create using virtual raster, but no values in each band and the raster didnt show up anything. But on the histogram there is a spectral curve for each band
[image: Histogram]
[image: Information of pixel value]

Comment: Are you images wide apart or adjacent?

Comment: Some of them is wide apart and some of them adjacent. Each file has 0.25x0.25 degrees size and 2 of them separated more than 0.5x1 degrees. Are the blank area is counted too?

Comment: Yes the blank areas will take consume disk space. Can you use a [virtual raster](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/vrt.html) instead?

Comment: The empty space is also filled with pixels. It tiff is uncompressed then empty pixels take as much disk space than the real ones. Empty pixels are easy to compress and file size will decrease much with options like `-co COMPRESS=deflate -co PREDICTOR=3`. However, I would also consider using a virtual raster.

Comment: Rasters are rectangular grids of pixels so each pixel, even your "blank" areas requires the same bits of info.  The suggested compression and virtual raster options can greatly reduce the data needed for those "blank" areas but you might also look at the bit depth of your images.  If you only need 256 shades of gray but your rasters are 16 or 32 bit, then you could convert your images to 8 bit which could greatly reduce file size.  It also makes the deflate or lzw compression more effective.

Comment: I already using virtual raster but the raster didnt show up. Meanwhile I check the histogram it has many values but in the map didnt have a visual of the raster.

Comment: It seems that you have placed every image into a separate band in the VRT and the result is an 8-band image. I believe that you want to have 1-band image that contains all the 8 input images.

Comment: No, each imageries has 4 bands and I want it to merge it in 1 raster that still has 4 bands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inputs are compressed and you are creating a non compressed output? Try adding a compression:

[image]

Comment: I already edited my question and adding my image so you can imagine how my image was. Does the compression reduce the quality of my imagery? And what about the pixel value?

Comment: Try and find out

Comment: This answered my question well. It turns out that the main problem besides of the size of the raster, 2/8 of my rasters was different projection. I already check the "Allow projection difference" but still didnt show up the two rasters earlier. Do you know how to solve it?? Besides of changing to WGS84